# Click button, insert text from that button

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm just starting with VBA and i'm stuck on a userform.

I am looking for a method that will allow me to click a command button and the text that is on that button will then appear in the last blank cell in a certain column. (for exemple in A2)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If MsgBox("Please confirm your choice ?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation") = vbYes Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        ligne = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A456541").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("A2").Select Range("A2").Value = "Multiproject" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
End Sub
```

After pen comment, my code looks like this :

Private Sub Multiproject_Click()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim NextFreeCell As Range ' find next free cell in column A
Set NextFreeCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)

If MsgBox("Please confirm your choice?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation") = vbYes Then
    NextFreeCell.Value = "Multiproject" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
End If

Unload FrmCustomMsgbo
```

End Sub
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rGKP.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: Hello Pen, thank you for your advices :)

For now my code is "
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If MsgBox("Please confirm your choice ?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation") = vbYes Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
ligne = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A456541").End(xlUp).Row + 1
End If

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A2").Select
Range("A2").Value = "Multiproject" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
End Sub"

I would like my code not to appear on A2 but on the first blank cell on the column A

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the code there formatted as code block. Code in coments gets useless due to missign formating.

Answer (score 1):

Just find the next free cell and write the value there:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim NextFreeCell As Range ' find next free cell in column A
    Set NextFreeCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1)

    If MsgBox("Please confirm your choice?", vbYesNo, "Confirmation") = vbYes Then
        NextFreeCell.Value = "Multiproject" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    End If
End Sub
```

You might benefit from reading
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

And I highly recommend to give your command button a useful name `CommandButton1` is not useful at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help and your advices. I changed my command buttons. Unfortunately, when I run the code it doesn't give me any result. The word "multiproject" does not appear in my excel cell.

Comment: @GuillaumeChomienne Does the code run at all? Does the message box *"Please confirm your choice?"* appear?

Comment: The message box appears with the message "pls confirm your choice". 
Then or it does nothing if the previous line was already "multiproject" , or it replace the last NON EMPTY cell...

Comment: @GuillaumeChomienne Ahh, my bad. See my edit. I forgot `.Offset(RowOffset:=1)`. Now it should work.